# Spy intent from external SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I'm writing an Android application with DJI-SDK to monitor when a video is recording. My drone uses its control application, but I need to spy on the drone's camera activity to send a notification when a new video has started recording, but I can't to have two Android applications use the DJI SDK at the same time.

Can I listen a "message or intent" sent by DJI-SDK service which will allow me to send a notification of a new recording video?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot listen in on the DJI app but if you write your own app you could broadcast camera activity that can na picked up by another app.

Look away broadcasters in android,  there are ways to publicly broadcast between apps or services.